# Restore image with negative colors

Tags: color, gimp, restoration

I have an image that was taken using a negative color filter long ago, but now I need the normal picture, is there a way to get a good quality of that picture with the actual colors?
The current software I am using is GIMP.

Comment: Photoshop has `Image > Adjustments > Invert`, and I'm sure other raster editor have something similar.

Comment: I have no clue, but a Google gives me [this](http://docs.gimp.org/nl/gimp-layer-invert.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIMP has an [invert command](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-invert.html) you can apply to RGB and Grayscale images:

[image] to  [image]

You can acces it through `Colors` → `Invert`.

Answer (score 9):

We may be talking about a scanned color negative film stock widely used way before the invention of digital cameras.

These images had a yellow and a red mask for color absorption. Hence negatives had an orange rather than a white tint:

[image]

<sup>Image source: [Wikipedia cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimslo#mediaviewer/File:Nimslostripneg.jpg)</sup>

To obtain a positve color image from these sources we have to

1. **Remove the orange mask**

   - *Colors > Pick white point:* choose an area outside the image

   [image]
2. **Invert the colors**

   - *Colors > Invert*

   [image]
3. **Adjust colors** (many negatives will have a heavy blue tint):

   - *Colors > Pick gray point:* choose a gray area from the image

   [image]

**Note:** removing the orange mask will unfortunately lead to a reduced pixel information as compared to color scans.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! OP mentions "was created with negative filter", so I think he means an actual digital image. Still, if this doesn't answer it we should definitely open a new question about film negatives and migrate this answer to it!

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled upon "long ago" but unless the OP clarifies this we probably wont't find out ;)